# passing display object to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function with this signature:

```
function startTimer(duration, display)
```

I have to call this in my ajax success and pass in a  display to this function.

This is what I'm doing but it doesn't work:

```
startTimer(2222,$("#example"));
```

Can someone tell what is the problem?

EDIT: here is my function

```
"use strict";

setInterval(function () {
    if(duration<0)
    {
        return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(duration / (60*60*24));
    var days_raw = days * (60*60*24);
    var  hours = Math.floor((duration-days_raw) / (60*60));
    var hours_raw = hours * (60*60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((duration-(hours_raw + days_raw)) / (60));
    var minutes_raw = minutes * (60);
    var  seconds = Math.floor(duration-(hours_raw + days_raw + minutes_raw));
    var seconds_raw = seconds;
    if(days>0)
    {
        if(days===1){
            display.text(days+" Day");
        }
        else{display.text(days+" Days");}
    }
    else if(days<=0)
    { if(seconds<10)
    {
        seconds= "0"+seconds;
    }
     if(minutes<10)
     {
         minutes= "0"+minutes;
     }
     if(hours<10)
     {
         hours= "0"+hours;
     }
     display.text(hours+":"+minutes + ":" + seconds);
    }
    duration--;

}, 1000);
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Can we see wat your function is doing?

Comment: @nikhil it doesn't take $("example") as my display

Comment: Can you provide jsFiddler link with exact issue?

Comment: You need to add more code in order to understand and fix your issue

Comment: Does `#example` exist in the DOM when you are calling the method? Also see `clearInterval` your return doesn't stop the interval.

Comment: @nikhil I added the code

Comment: @SebastianNette #example is in a modal page which opens on click

Comment: Is your modal even open?

Comment: @code yes it is open

Comment: It's not open. That's why your `var display= $("#example");` works in your interval. It's open at the time the interval happens, but not open at the time the function is invoked.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I fixed it this way:

```
var display= $("#example");
```

Comment: If you don't know why it fixed a problem that you didn't even know about, pls don't bother to post an answer!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the rest of Your code, but try:

```
startTimer(2222,$("#example").val());
```

or

```
startTimer(2222,$("#example").html());
```

$("#example") is just a pointer to an object. You need to choose what do You want to do with it. By .val() You can set value of element eg.

```
<input name="demo" id="example" value"ChangeMe">
```

by using .html() you can change something like

```
<div id="example">ChangeMe</div>
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/val/ and http://api.jquery.com/html/